# react-native-reanimated & react-navigation/drawer dependency error

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2, react-native-debugger, react-native-drawer

I'm into a problem that I have already asked the discussions tab in the `react-native-reanimated` GitHub repository: this is the link [in the github repo](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/discussions/2558)

I have cloned a react-native project and tried to install npm packages using npm install, but I have faced the error below

[image]

What I have done?

- I have tried npm install --legacy-peer-deps, was not helpful
- I have installed the packages from scratch, was not helpful
- I have tried yarn to install packages the error was gone but the issue persisted
- I have also tried configuring the flipper on the application but the app also does not
  connect to the flipper

Any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is going to be solved by just running npm with `--legacy-peer-deps`, this is going to tell the npm just don't do anything else except looking into the `package-lock.json` file and install the versions that you used to have in your `node_modules` folder.

```sh
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

I should mention that you are going to see this output while you are using npm version 7 or above.